# Cannot call member function const without object when using call by reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

Hi together I have following class defined in 'cstring.h':

```
namespace BaseTypes {

class CString {
    private:
        character *ptrCString = NULL; //Init pointer always with NULL!
        character *createSafeCString(character cStringToCheck[]);
        size_t inline length(const CString &cString) const;
        size_t inline internalLength();
    public:
        CString(character cstring[]);
        ~CString();
        integer length();
        CString& operator+=(const CString& rhs);
        friend CString operator+(CString lhs, const CString &rhs);
    };

}
```

and the 'cstring.cpp':

```
namespace BaseTypes {
    //Constructor with a char array
    CString::CString(character cstring[]) {
        ptrCString = createSafeCString(cstring);
    }
    ...
    size_t inline CString::length(const CString &cString) const {
        return strlen(cString.ptrCString);
    }
    ...
     CString operator+(CString lhs, const CString &rhs) {
        size_t thisSize = lhs.internalLength();
        size_t rhsSize = CString::length(rhs);
        character *newCString = new character[thisSize + rhsSize + 1];

        strncpy(newCString, lhs.ptrCString, thisSize);
        strncat(newCString, rhs.ptrCString, rhsSize);

        newCString[thisSize + rhsSize] = '\0';
        CString *cString = new CString(newCString);
        return *cString;
    }
}
```

That gives me an compile error:

```
In function 'BaseTypes::CString BaseTypes::operator+(BaseTypes::CString, BaseTypes::CString&)':
C:\Sources\Projekte\base\types\cstring.cpp:78:45: error: cannot call member function 'size_t BaseTypes::CString::length(const BaseTypes::CString&) const' without object size_t rhsSize = CString::length(rhs);
```

And I am stuck. I do not have any clue. What did I miss. Isn't this a reference to a const CString already....

Comment: I don't C any C here!

Comment: `CString::length(rhs)` would work if `length` was a static member, but it is not.

Comment: What is unclear about the error message?

Comment: the whole private `size_t inline length(const CString &cString) const;` contraption doesn't make any sense - why isn't it just `public: size_t inline length() const;` and done...

Comment: it's not public because I do not want to make it puplic. The class CString should only have a few methods on public access.

Comment: `strncat(newCString, rhs.ptrCString, rhsSize);` will not do what you think.  The size is one too small.

Comment: Should not `size_t inline CString::length(const CString &cString) const` be a `friend`?

Comment: The C-like code `strncpy(newCString, lhs.ptrCString, thisSize);
        strncat(newCString, rhs.ptrCString, rhsSize);

        newCString[thisSize + rhsSize] = '\0';` could be replaced with `memcpy(newCString, lhs.ptrCString, thisSize);  memcpy(newCString + thisSize, rhs.ptrCString, rhsSize + 1);`

Comment: @Code.IT so in your opinion the string class shouldn't have a public method that would tell the length of the string?

Comment: There is no "**call** by reference".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have declared `length()` as a member function, and member functions expect to operate on a given object.  Calling a member function with an argument as you are via `CString::length(rhs)` passes the value of `rhs` as the argument to the function, but does not tell the `length` method which object to actually call the method on, so no `this` pointer is meaningful..   You do not appear to need the value of `this` in your `length`, function, however, so you could declare the method as `static`, and then calling it via `CString::length(rhs)` would work as you seem to expect.

A more OO-centric solution would be to leave `length` as a non-static member function that takes no arguments and make it operate on `this` instead of an explicit argument, and it could be below as `rhs.length()`.   This is, however, just a matter of style, and is not really any more correct than the more imperative approach you appear to already be accustomed to.